# How to cache php pages

Tags: php, caching

Hello i have a problem with my website. It is running slow. I asked the my server provider why is that, and they replied its because the webiste uses many embedded urls like youtube, vimeo, dailymotion and so on. And so i have to cache these embedded urls. Anyone knows how to do that?
I viewed this online. So all i have to do is put this code on my config page?

http://www.phpfastcache.com/

```
I downloaded the files. On the examble.php
```

what do iput on $contents?

```
<?php
include("php_fast_cache.php");
phpFastCache::$storage = "auto";
// ready ?
// check in case first
$content = phpFastCache::get("keyword1");
if($content == null) {
// for testing
echo "This is not caching, page is render with lot queires and slow speed <br>";
// do what you want, like get content from cURL | API | mySQL Query and return result to $content
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.phpfastcache.com/testing.php");
// rewrite cache for other request in 5 seconds
phpFastCache::set("keyword1",$content,5);
} else {
// use cache
// node
echo "THIS TIME USE CACHE, FAST! <br>";
}
echo "TRY F5 to refesh the page to see new SPEED with Cache!<br>";
echo $content;
```

why is this line?
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.phpfastcache.com/testing.php");

Answer (score 0):

> what do iput on $contents?

Contents would be the data that you are attempting to save. I.E

$contents = "Hello World!";

Or...

$contents = ['video_url' => 'youtube.com/v?=1234534'];

> why is this line?

That line is simply retrieving the contents of testing.php into a string.

From what it sounds like, any sort of PHP caching wont do any good if your main issue is because of embedded videos... If however you are displaying one video at a time on a page and the videos are hidden because of a Javascript. I would recommend using PHP to load the embedded video based on the URL instead.

I.E - Assuming if your not using a database to display videos.

Website Address
http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/?v=1

```
<?php //INSERT THIS WHERE YOU WANT A VIDEO TO DISPLAY.
switch($_GET['v'])
{
     case 1:
        echo '<YOUTUBE EMBEDDED HTML HERE>';
     break;

     case 2:
        echo '<VIMEO EMBEDDED HTML HERE>';
     break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Post what you have so far, and maybe me or someone else can help you out a little better...

https://gist.github.com/

Comment: the urls are stored in the database, and i return them as a variable. I use the code on the page that i call the urls-videos\

Comment: $contents = ['video_url' => $my_video_url];

Comment: $content = file_get_contents("http://www.mywebpage.com/same_page_as_the_code.php"); And i dont get anything

Answer (score 0):

the urls are stored in the database. so if i want to cache the url. i ll write this

```
include("php_fast_cache.php");
```

phpFastCache::$storage = "auto";

$content = phpFastCache::get($url);

echo "TRY F5 to refesh the page to see new SPEED with Cache!
"; echo $content;

$url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVoRw5qWc2o